# verifying that multiple strings are in required order with assert_match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

How can I verify the order of strings using assert_match

```
assert_match /string_1.*string_2.*string_3/, page.html
```

is failing even though `string_1`, `string_2`, and `string_3` appear in the same order in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that "string_1", "string_2" and "string_3" are on different lines.

In a regular expression, the dot (`.`) matches any single character except line breaks. You will see that the match works if the three strings are on the same line (ie no line breaks in between):

```
html = '<div>string_1</div><div>string_2</div><div>string_3</div>'
p html.match(/string_1.*string_2.*string_3/)
#=> #<MatchData "string_1</div><div>string_2</div><div>string_3">
```

However, if the strings are split across multiple lines (ie there are line breaks in between), there will be no match:

```
html = '<div>string_1</div>
    <div>string_2</div>
    <div>string_3</div>'
p html.match(/string_1.*string_2.*string_3/)
#=> nil
```

For the dot to also match line breaks, enable the multi-line option by adding `m` to the end:

```
html = '<div>string_1</div>
    <div>string_2</div>
    <div>string_3</div>'
p html.match(/string_1.*string_2.*string_3/m)
#=> #<MatchData "string_1</div>\n\t<div>string_2</div>\n\t<div>string_3">
```

In other words, the assertion likely needs to use the multi-line option:

```
assert_match /string_1.*string_2.*string_3/m, page.html
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following...

view:

```
string_1string_2string_3
```

test:

```
assert_match /string_1.*string_2.*string_3/, page.html
```

This passes.

I'm not sure what's giving you an issue. Unless of course `string_1` and so on are variable names and not literally what you're searching for. Then the test code should use interpolation:

```
# Example variables with string values
string_1 = "alpha"
string_2 = "beta"
string_3 = "charlie"

# Using the variables in the regex via interpolation
assert_match /#{string_1}.*#{string_2}.*#{string_3}/, page.html
```

Comment: Thanks. Turned out it was an issue with multi-line text. Justin Ko's answer helped.